# ScrollView not working properly

Tags: android, scrollview

[image]

The scroll bar that I have added in the following program does not work as it should.

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#D3D3D3">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Over the years, Techfest's presence has been felt internationally. The technology that is being promoted has had tremendous impact on all the participants of the festival. This year Techfest provides an international platform to it's participants in some versatile competitions. Such a platform is necessary to promote exchange of ideas and exposure to participants.
Techfest welcomes you to International Challenge, where knowledge crosses borders.
"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/robowars"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bullet_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:text="RoboWars"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/irc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bullet_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:text="International Robotics Challenge"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

JAVA File

```
public class IntChal extends Fragment {
    public IntChal() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.intchal, container, false);
    }
}
```

For this file, the scroll bar does not work at all, i.e, it doesn't scroll.But the exact same logic seems to work properly for another tab. What changes should I be making? Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

I got a trend in the error. It always doesn't show the last button in the file. Hope this helps.

Comment: May be your content, is not exceeding the screen size.

Comment: Just change height to fill_parent.And its content should higher than it.

Comment: No. My content is more than the screen size. and @tiny sunlight, i tried that. still not working though

Comment: Plz shou me your content screenshot. I try on my preview,it's small than screen.

Comment: This form has two buttons, but only one is visible due to it not scrolling

Comment: How to add screenshot to stackoverflow?

Comment: Just edit and see a icon lick picture.

Comment: I added the photo link (rep prob) , and according to the photo i have two buttons, but my phone only shows me one

Comment: screenshot of you phone!

Answer (score 0):

Scroll View Will work only if content exceeds ScreenSize. For more details visit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: My content is exceeding the screen size. Its not showing one of the two buttons in my xml file, but will not scroll down either

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the parent layout to the scroll view i.e. Relative layout or linear layout..i.e

for example

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">




//here add your scrollview or other layout watever you have written  above (This is just for referance)
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Now its scrolling, but still does not scroll all the way down.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan: it has reached its end .

Answer (score 0):

Just change height to fill_parent.

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</ScrollView>
```